# wget not available on AWS EC2 (Bitnami)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, wget

I'm currently running a Bitnami Wordpress AMI on an EC2 instance (micro). When I connect to the machine via SSH and I try to execute `wget` I get the message `command not found`.

I tried to install it using `apt-get` but it's not available either. How can I install it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Amazon Linux the command is:

```
sudo yum install wget
```